# how do i apply security configuration on existing emr cluster using boto3?

Tags: hadoop, aws-lambda

I am new to aws emr services. I am trying to add security configuration to already created emr cluster using boto3. Please reply if it is possible to do so or is there any alternative solution to achive the same

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried so far? (Please show your code.)

Comment: I have created emr using cloudformation template but not able to add security configuration into it, so created lambda function but not able to call from cf template. due to character restriction not able to attach code here please provide your email so that i can show whatever i have done so far

Comment: So you have an existing Amazon EMR cluster and you want to use CloudFormation to create a new Security Group for use on the cluster? Or do you wish to modify the Security Group that the cluster is already using? Please provide as much information as possible so that we can assist you.

Comment: Actually I am trying to use “security configurations “ to implement EMR encryption at rest and in transit, but there doesn’t seems to be any way of specifying “security configurations “ while creating EMR from Cloudformation, Therefore thought to do security configuration  using lambda function and calling lambda function from cloudformation while creating EMR cluster, unfortunately in lambda (Python 2.7 boto3) also there is no way of adding security configuration in an already created EMR cluster. Hope I am clear now if you need more information please let me know. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Specifying Amazon EMR Encryption Options Using a Security Configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-encryption-enable-security-configuration.html) documentation page says:

> Using a security configuration to specify cluster encryption settings is a two-step process. First, you create a security configuration, which you can use for any number of clusters. Then you specify the security configuration to use when you create a cluster.

Therefore, you will need to **create the Security Configuration before launching the EMR cluster**. It is not possible to add the Security Configuration to an existing cluster.

At the time of writing (April 2017), there is no Security Configuration available in AWS CloudFormation therefore the template should:

- Call a **Lambda function** (via an [AWS Lambda-backed Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html)) that calls [create_security_configuration()](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.create_security_configuration) to create a Security Configuration
- Create the **EMR cluster** using the Security Configuration, with a `DependsOn` attribute that waits for the Lambda function to complete before creating the cluster

**Update:** It is not currently (April 2017) possible to specify a Security Configuration when launching a cluster via CloudFormation. So, this method is not currently supported.

Comment: Appreciate your quick response, I am trying this approach but facing issue in Lambda function -create_security_configuration() in this function I am setting up SecurityConfiguration variable value in json format but getting Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter SecurityConfiguration" error. could you please suggest how should I specify value here.

Comment: One more doubt I have here, suppose the create_security_configuration() executed as per expectations then how could this configuration get attached to emr cluster on the fly. Rather I could say I have already created security configuration using IAM but not found any way to apply the same while creating emr cluster using cloudformation

Comment: Ah! You're totally right! CloudFormation doesn't support *creation* of Security Configurations -- and neither does it support *referencing* a Security Configuration when launching a cluster. So, it is not possible in CloudFormation until they add this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For Googlers:

- EMRFS encryption options **CANNOT BE CHANGED** after cluster creation
- There is no way to associate a new security configuration to a cluster, also
- If you turn on SSE on buckets only new objects are encrypted, which is not desired
- If you turn on CSE then all objects will be read and write with an encryptor so it would break the file system
- So, no changes are allowed