# Cloning existing EMR cluster into a new one using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

When creating a new cluster using boto3, I want to use configuration from existing clusters (which is terminated) and thus clone it.
As far as I know, `emr_client.run_job_flow` requires all the configuration(`Instances, InstanceFleets etc`) to be provided as parameters. 
Is there any way I can clone from existing cluster like I can do from aws console for EMR.

[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579746/how-do-i-apply-security-configuration-on-existing-emr-cluster-using-boto3

Comment: Please read both the questions.They are different.

Comment: @AmeyDahale Have you got the answer? Seems that should be a popular function for boto3 to clone an existing EMR.

Comment: I have kept a static config file with all EMR details and using boto3's [run_job_flow](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow) to reuse the existing EMR's properties. /i guess it would be good to have boto3 function to clone existing EMR.

Comment: I created this issue (albeit on the java sdk), since i see this is such a common request: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/2002

Answer (score 1):

What i can recommend you, is using the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-cluster.html) to fire your Cluster.
It permit to versioning your cluster configuration and you can easily load steps configuration with a **json** file.

```
aws create-cluster --name "Cluster's name" --ec2-attributes KeyName=SSH_KEY --instance-type m3.xlarge --release-label emr-5.2.1 --log-uri s3://mybucket/logs/ --enable-debugging --instance-count 1 --use-default-roles --applications Name=Spark --steps file://step.json
```

Where **step.json** looks like :

```
     [
      {
        "Name": "Step #1",
        "Type":"SPARK",
        "Jar":"command-runner.jar",
        "Args":
        [
          "--deploy-mode", "cluster",
          "--class", "com.your.data.set.class",
          "s3://path/to/your/spark-job.jar",
          "-c", "s3://path/to/your/config/or/not",
          "--aws-access-key", "ACCESS_KEY",
          "--aws-secret-key", "SECRET_KEY"
        ],
        "ActionOnFailure": "CANCEL_AND_WAIT"
      }
     ]
```

(Multiple steps is okey too)

After that you can always startUp the same configured Cluster.
And for example Schedule the whole Cluster and steps from one **[AirFlow](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/)** job.

But if you really want to use **Boto3**, i suppose that the [describe_cluster()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.describe_cluster) method can help you to get the whole informations and use the returned object to Fire Up a new one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get "emr export cli" through command line.
You should parse the parameter what you want to clone, through "describe-cluster".

See below sample,
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/EMR/Get_EMR_CLI_Export

```
import boto3
import json
import sys

cluster_id = sys.argv[1]
client = boto3.client('emr')
clst = client.describe_cluster(ClusterId=cluster_id)

...

awscli += ' --steps ' + '\'' + json.dumps(cli_steps) + '\''

...

awscli += ' --instance-groups ' + '\'' + json.dumps(cli_igroups) + '\''
print(awscli)
```

It works parsing the parameters from “describe-cluster” at first, and make strings to fit “create-cluster” of aws-cli.